# JS Regex .replace, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to perform a simple regex replace in javascript to replace new lines \n with html breaks

```
var strings = 'Hello world
This is a test.
Multi-line.';

stringt = strings.replace( '/(\r\n|\n|\r)/gm', '<br />' );
alert(stringt);
```

Testing the RegEx pattern on a couple of online testers has proven successful, I guess I'm just missing something real dumb?

Comment: That's not how multi-line work in JS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You can't define strings like that.**

You can do multiline strings like this though

```
var str = "Hello world\n\
This is a test.\n\
Multi-line.";
```

Then this regexp will work for you

```
str.replace(/[\r\n]+/g, "<br>");
```

Notice that regexp in JavaScript are not enclosed in quotes `"` like they are in langs like PHP.

---

Per @alex's comment, you could create the regexp like this

```
 var re = new RegExp('[\r\n]+', 'g');
 str.replace(re, "<br>");
```

In this case, you use a string, but no `/` delimiters.

Comment: Thanks, removing the quotes did it!

Comment: Note to OP: regexes are only quoted when used with the `RegExp` constructor.